# SAP BusinessObjects InfoView translation

Tags: translation, business-objects, infoview

I need to translate SAP BO InfoView interface. The language we require doesn't have native BO language pack.

I discovered a bunch of .properties files, translated them, but not all of the texts was converted.

Maybe someone could give me some advices, or some ideas for solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think any text not in the properties or xml config files are in 2 main places:

1. Hard coded in the JSP files.  A general search and replace should work at finding where these are.
2. The Java applet WebI controller.  This one is compiled and packaged jar.  I believe this is where the text that you haven't been able to translate yet resides.  This one will be trickier to update and changes to it will most likely end any support from SAP if you run into troubles.